# Which store type sells the maximum products by the value of sales amount & by quantity sold

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to use only single SELECT statement. Multiple select statements are not allowed.

I have a table named "Transactions" which has the following variables:

- **Qty** - *It has total Quantities ordered for a particular product*
- **total_amt** - *It has Amount paid by customers for the particular products*
- **Store_type** - *It has transaction channels*

For example, if Qty ordered are 5 and price of each quantity of product is 100. then total_amt would be carrying 500.

Now I have to find the Store type that sells the maximum products by the value of sales amount & by quantity sold. I have to do this using sub queries in Having clause.

I have written the following code in SQL Server but it is not giving me any output and throwing the error that Transactions.total_amt should be included in having clause or aggregated function. On using total_amt in group by, I am not getting any result in the output.

Below is the query which I have written :

```
select store_type, MAX(total_amt), MAX(Qty)
from Transactions
group by Store_type
Having total_amt = (select SUM(total_amt) from Transactions group by Store_type)
AND
Qty = (select SUM(Qty) from Transactions group by Store_type)
```

Comment: Use the code formatting button to edit your question (to be easier to read).

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text (not link to image)

Comment: What is your input data, and what results do you get using your current query? (This question lacks a [mcve], and so is off-topic. It can be easily edited to make it on-topic).

Comment: @Mohit Kumar you say *I have to find the Store type that sells the maximum products* does this mean the maximum total quantity? If so why do you sum the amount also? You know that maybe the store which sold the max quantity is not also the store which had the max amount.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is based  on max order by and limit

```
select store_type, MAX(total_amt), MAX(Qty)
from Transactions
group by Store_type
ORDER BY  MAX(total_amt) DESC,  MAX(Qty) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check both query result and identify store type wise total amt and max total amt matching with qty or not.

If you want only matched then you can create 2 sub query tables and use inner join.

I hope this will resolve.

```
select 
Store_type,
SUM(total_amt) AS Total_total_amt,
SUM(Qty) AS Total_Qty
from Transactions 
group by Store_type


select 
store_type, 
MAX(total_amt) AS max_total_amt, 
MAX(Qty) AS max_Qty
from Transactions 
group by Store_type
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the query You suggested is generating a blank output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query as shown below

;With cte as
(
Select sum(qty) as sum_quantity,sum(sales) as sum_sales,store_type
From transaction
Group by store_type
)

Select Max(sum_quantity),max(sum_sales),store_type from cte
Group by store_type

Answer (score 0):

```
Select store_type
From transactions
Where total_amt > 0 and qty>0 
Group by store_type
Order by sum(total_amt) desc,sum(qty) desc ;
```